# Retain filtering option when paginating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I'm trying to add a new feature to this pagination/filtering script but so far, without succes. I want that, when you change the page, the filter you picked from the top right corner select (that with "**Ordonare dupa...**) to remain picked instead of switching back to the first option.

This is my website - http://www.wheelsmarket.ro/cautare/jante/1

To paginate/filter i used this function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.sortare').on('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/filtrare-jante.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'selected' : $(this).val(), 'pagina_id' : <?php echo $_GET['pagina'];?>},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); // do something with what is returned
            $('#myTest').html(data);
            $('#queryInitial').html('null');
        }
    });
});
```

All the querys are made inside a #myTest div, and the myTest div gets changed without reloading when you change that select. The problem is that the select box is out of #myTest div, so i doubt that i can make use of that function i have.
ex:

```
<select class="sortare select" >
    <option value="1">cele mai noi</option>
    <option value="2">cele mai ieftine</option>
    <option value="3">cele mai scumpe</option>
</select>
<div id="myTest">
code
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you need something like :

1) Add id to your options:

```
<select class="sortare select" >
    <option id="sel1" value="1">cele mai noi</option>
    <option id="sel2" value="2">cele mai ieftine</option>
    <option id="sel3" value="3">cele mai scumpe</option>
</select>
<div id="myTest">
code
</div>
```

AND change tha attr() to selected in jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.sortare').on('change', function(){
    selValue = $(this).val(); //---> Store this value in a variable.
    $.ajax({
        url: '/filtrare-jante.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'selected' : $(this).val(), 'pagina_id' : <?php echo $_GET['pagina'];?>},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); // do something with what is returned
            $('#myTest').html(data);
            $('#queryInitial').html('null');
            $('#sel'+selValue).attr("selected","selected"); //---> Use the variable we created to determine which option should be set to selected dynamically
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: First, i think that the function is missing a pair of enclosing brackets, like '});'. Second, it did not worked. I added the missing brackets by myself but after you change a page, it still does not retain the value you selected.